# subscripting using itemgetter vs zip python

Tags: python

Pardon my title if it does not match the question. I am trying to understand where I went wrong with zip. itemgetter generates the correct result but zip
does not. Does it have anything to do with my unpacking the list or did I go about it the wrong way? My intention is to remove all last values in the
list if they are all zeros but I get a comma in the result for zip.

Here are the codes for just checking the last elements:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = ['0:0:2,0,1', '0:0:3,0,0', '0:1:1,3,0', '0:0:3,2,0', '0:0:0,1,0']
b = list(zip(*a))[-1]
c = list(map(itemgetter(-1), a))

print(b)
print(c)
```

Results

```
('1', '0', ',', '0', '0')

['1', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Please explanation will be helpful. Thank you much

Comment: Strange, when I run your code [on my machine](https://ideone.com/3flE1w), the zip approach gives `('1', '0', '0', '0', '0')`. Are you sure this is the exact code you're running?

Comment: Yes I am very sure it is. I am using spyder

Comment: Both b and c are the same for me as well.

Comment: Then I don't know what is wrong.  I feel like I do not want another import just to achieve this. I will go ahead and try with zip then